# Is there a way to determine if the current page is odd or even inside the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

At some point in the table of contents I have to make a pagebreak if the current page is odd but not if it's even. I already have a command which I use in my document and it's working well.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setCurPage}{
  \ifodd\c@page
    \renewcommand{\curPage}{\right}
  \else
    \renewcommand{\curPage}{\left}
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

I use it like:

```
\setCurPage\ifnum\curPage=\right\clearpage\fi
```

But if I add this code to my toc file the value of \curPage depends on the page where the table of contents begins and not on the actual page. It also would do for me if I knew, is it the first, second, third or other page of the table of contents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to protect your macro when it's added to the table of contents otherwise it's expanded and uses the current value of the page number (or creates all kind of errors).

You can see what's going on by looking in `\jobname.toc`.

Try this, which uses `\NewDocumentCommand` to define a protected macro which can safely be included in the table of contents.

I also used `\usepackage[strict]{changepage}` for checking the page number as there are some situations when checking the page counter can be unreliable. (Although I confess I don't know if this is one of them. It does seem to work without the `strict` option which falls back to just checking `\c@page`.) The downside of use `strict` is that an extra run of LaTeX is required.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

\NewDocumentCommand{\clearpageifodd}{}{%
  \checkoddpage
  \ifoddpage
    \clearpage
  \fi}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{First section}

\addtocontents{toc}{\clearpageifodd}

\section{Second section}

\addtocontents{toc}{\clearpageifodd}

\section{Third section}

\section{Fourth section}

\end{document}
```

When you look in `\jobname.toc` you will find:

```
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}First section}{2}{}%
\clearpageifodd 
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2}Second section}{2}{}%
\clearpageifodd 
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3}Third section}{2}{}%
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4}Fourth section}{2}{}%
```

And there will be a page break after *First section*, but not after *Second section*.

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution works as expected!